# ngGrid editable checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, datagrid, ng-grid

I just spent several hours trying to get an editable checkbox element in a ngGrid.
If I use a `type=text` input everything works fine, when I change it to `type=checkbox` it stops working.

I've tried all combinations of ng-input, ng-model and ng-checked, none seem to work (some don't work at all, some change the value in the model, but then nothing happens).

I was unable to find any example on the groups nor on the wiki.

Futhermore when I just use the "default" editable template (`<input ng-class="'colt' + col.index" ng-input="COL_FIELD" />`) I get a JS exception "No controller: ngModel".

Is this thing completely useless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so seemingly what breaks it is `enableCellEditOnFocus : true`, if you just use `enableCellEdit : true,` it works.